# tortoise svn commit won't show some of my files

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have merged few bat and xml files from one branch to another.  After merging, I was able to see all my files merged properly (these files were already in the branch I was merging to).

However, when I tried committing, under "changes made" section I only saw four of my files.  Two were missing.  The missing files had xml extension.  I am afraid to commit since I do not see all of my files in the list.

Has anone ever encounter this problem before?

Comment: Have you added the files yet? Maybe you didn't check the boxes of the new files in the commit dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to <kbd>Check Out</kbd> your repository in another directory, at previous revision from this commit. Verify if your files are there.

If not, I'm afraid that your files were never versioned. Otherwise, verify if the files have the old content before your commit.